# What material is the white part on Deadpool's eyes on his Mask made of?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

For him to be able to see out of his mask, what is the eye part made of?

[image]

This is considering that he was making the suit and mask himself in the movie,

And finally we see the finished suit, so what was the white part of the eyes made of, so he could see through them?

Comment: IMHO, it's a tribute to comics; I actually expected Deadpool to mock his and other's suits, but alas...

Comment: Related: [Eye part mask of Spider-Man and Deadpool](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52899/49)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no canon answer, but [cosplayers have been solving this issue for decades](http://www.therpf.com/showthread.php?t=137821). Basically, your options come down to:

- Fine metal or plastic mesh - Surprisingly easy to see through but seemingly opaque even close up.
- Translucent plastic - Obscures one's vision more, but very opaque.
- Scrim fabric - Not very good for low-light scenarios
- Buckram - Relatively stiff material already used for mask-masking. Oddly enough, you have to paint it to be able to see through it as otherwise it's too reflective.

Comment: Damn it, I'm almost sure there was a gag about this in the latest Deadpool game, but I can't remember it

Comment: so... cosplaying has been going on for how many decades? I thought it was a post-2K thing.

Comment: @Spandan: Technically, it's been going on since the 1930s with the "futuricostumes" at the Worlds Fair, but the 1970s are probably more recognizable between Rocky Horror and the ComicArt costumes (http://www.enjolrasworld.com/Richard%20Arndt/Angelique%20The%20Unconventional%20ComiCon%20Costumer.htm)